# Alter database to match model

Tags: mysql-workbench

Originally, I used Data Modelling in MySQL Workbench to design a database consisting of a series of tables (i.e. the columns and relationships).

Then using Database -> Forward Engineer, I created a database, and inserted data into the tables.

Now I've realised that the model I've designed needs some changes, and so I've altered some tables by inserted columns.  My question is, how do I get MySQL Workbench to alter the tables?

Using Database -> Synchronize Model, Update Source just generates a bunch of CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sql statements, and as the tables exist, nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I couldn't get get `File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL ALTER Script` to work, so I made a backup of the data, dropped the tables, recreated them, and then imported the data.  I'd rather find a way to get MySQL Workbench to generate ALTER commands from the changes in my model

Comment: this seems to be not available anymore

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is in the model menu *Database / Synchronize model*.

Answer (score 0):

The 2011 answer is no longer up to date. I struggled to find the option in a recent version. Here is the new procedure (works for MySQLWorkbench 6.2 at least):

When you have finished editing your model, open `Database -> Synchronize with Any Source`

In the step `Select Source` you have 3 parts

- **Source** : choose `Model Schemadata`
- **Destination** : choose `Live Database Server`
- **Send updates to** : choose whether the live database should be updated or if you only want to saves the changes to a `.sql` file

Proceed in the wizard, you can then review the tables and sql queries that will be executed. You can also ignore the update of some tables.